# Unable to track new product on an existing GA account (testing on 2 different properties)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm encountering a very strange issue:

My client has multiple properties on their account, and multiple products with subdomains are successfully tracked through one main universal clientsite.org property.

For some reason, the newest product/subdomain--new.clientsite.org and its view/filter capturing that subdomain I added-- is *not* tracking. It's not showing any traffic whatsoever, including live traffic from myself. The main clientsite.org domain and other subdomains are working great. The view/filters I created for new.clientsite.org are identical to the other subdomains, but filtering to include ^new.clientsite.org instead of ^old.clientsite.org. But views/filters aside: this property is flat out not recording any traffic to  hostname new.clientsite.org.

In case(?) it's related to any domain or dns issues, I set up a second property on the same account, defining the URI as the IP instead,  hostname xx.xx.xxx.xxx and we added that snippet to the site as well. This is also not picking up anything.

My developer has, from the get go, been tracking this through his own separate account/property he created for the domain of http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx and that's picking up *everything*! As far as I can tell, his property--which is quite basic-- is identical to the xx.xx.xxx.xxx property I set up on the client account (yes, we are using separate tracking code snippets). His property captures all visits to new.clientsite.org and xx.xx.xxx.xxx both (I haven't created separate views/filters in there to separate out domains because this property was supposed to be temporary. But it's the only one working!)

So, this product is using 3 tracking code snippets--and the 2 snippets attached to their own clientsite.org account are not working. His hostname xx.xx.xxx.xxx property and the clientsite.org  hostname xx.xx.xxx.xxx property settings seem to be identical, but for their unique certificate #'s.

Here's what we've ruled out so far:

- The issue isn't the code snippet: we're using GA native code for the clientsite.org property. (The other 2 test properties are using customized code for event tracking.)
- We have a test.html page running only this one native new.clientsite.org code snippet. This page isn't tracking us in real time either. So it's not a conflict with multiple accounts/snippets (not that that should be a problem).
- On the server running the product--which is using an elastic IP from AWS, and which has a correct A record associating the IP with new.clientsite.org as it has for the other subdomains in use--they have restarted Apache, in case there was any DNS caching.

Server admins I've spoken with are also flummoxed. None of us have ever seen a site refuse to "track."

One thing I thought could be an issue? Is that the main universal clientsite.org property recently enabled User ID tracking. This is specifically for one of their other subdomain products, which started registering users. The main clientsite.org domain and other subdomains which don't have user registrations are still tracking great--but they were pre-existing. I don't see how/why enabling User ID on the property may negatively affect new products from connecting using the same property certificate...

And though I initially did set up my other xx.xx.xxx.xxx test property on their account with User ID, I since disabled User ID there in case that was causing any issues (and to make it more identical to my developer's property that is tracking correctly).

Has anyone encountered issues with new products not tracking with the same GA account that's working for older/existing products?

Comment: It is common these days to put a white list domain filter on GA accounts.   This is done to prevent spammers from adding random data without visiting the site.   You can test this by creating a new view on the main GA property with no filters and see if it starts tracking in that.